# SSIS execution aborting on partial completion without error message

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl, sql-server-agent

In Visual Studio 2019 we are running 2 SSIS packages that return millions of records. When the DTSX packages are started separately in SSIS Catalog or SQL Server Agent only 3700913 and 3623554 records (much fewer than the expected amount) are imported.  The logging reports that the import succeeded successfully, however, there is no error message or explanation for why the import did not finish executing on all records.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more of the context, I can only suggest some potential solutions.

1. If the number of imported records is changing each time the packages are executed, I would verify that no one is attempting to use the file(s) being ran against while the packages are executing, perhaps inadvertently causing a file lock.
2. If the number of imported records is always 3700913 and 3623554 for both packages, perhaps whatever record is next in line contains an unexpected token or is an unexpected data type. I would hone in on the records around these positions to see if anything stands out to you.
3. Another possibility could be that perhaps the SSIS packages are dependent upon each other completing their respective executions, and this could be causing an early termination without an error message.
4. Lastly, there could be a corruption in the files themselves that is causing SSIS to believe it has completed execution short of what it should actually have done.